# Modal is not becoming visible using jquery in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, modal-dialog

I am trying to open a modal using jQuery in Wordpress. I wrote this functions, but it does not seem to open the modal...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(".open-modal").find("a").addClass("open-modal-2");

jQuery(".open-modal-2").click(function() {

    jQuery(".modal").addClass("modal--is-visible");
        return false;


 });
});
```

jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kfmurjf4/

Comment: Your JSfiddle does not include `jquery` CDN. If you add a jQuery CDN source it'll start working as you expect it to. Look for errors thrown by JS in Google Javascript console.

Comment: thanks :) so obvious....

Comment: I have posted my solution as an answer to this question. If this helped you, mark my answer as solution so that others looking for related solutions may find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this::

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');


var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}


window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abhishekgupta1994/xtbc7px8/

Comment: I think the problem with you solution is that it is out of OP's codebase. He has transitions etc using that specific class `modal--is-visible`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSfiddle does not include jquery. If you add a jQuery CDN source it'll start working as you expect it to.

Try this CDN

```
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/
```

Always look for errors thrown by JS in Google Javascript console.